# How to retrieve information via ajax from php file before a header redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I am trying to make my page somewhat more dynamic, i have a a forum made from scratch that i am implementing javaScript too now. All PHP is done. Now, i want to log in users without a page refresh and with some fading effects.

In my PHP file i have some validation and header redirects based on if the users enters the wrong password, the wrong username or if the user is successfully logged in. What i struggle with is to make some validation in javaScript using AJAX. I know that i can't output any before a header redirect, but how should i retrieve information from the PHP file if i can't?

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {
            //echo 'error_login';
            header('Location:../index.php?error=login&email='.$user_email);
            exit();
```

Here is a non working example due to output before header of what is similar to what i want to achieve. If the user fail's to login, the php file should prepare a message that i can retrieve through a AJAX call and use for client side validation.

Any thoughts or tips how i should go from here? Thanks in advance for all help i can get.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you get some education in Ajax before you start designing? Go there as a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started . This should not sound rude, but its better when you understand the mechanics before you start to develop your software ;-)

You don't "extract from PHP" with Ajax. PHP is still server-side processing, and Javascript (Ajax) is client side. Basically its just a slightliy different way for the client to communicate with the server - and it is ALWAYS client initiated.

To get what you want to achieve you would not redirect the client, but rather transmit userid/password by means of Ajax, getting the server response in Ajax as well. Then, on the client side, you can incorporate the server response into the structure of your web page, WITHOUT the need to reload the whole page or to move to a different URL.

But before you start, do your homework and learn what Ajax is all about.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, the code snippet i posted was only to show what i want to achieve, i still want to hear some thoughts about what i can do to achieve this, a way to fetch error messages via a AJAX call even if there are a header redirect in the php code.

Comment: @Dan-LeviTømtaHansen The point is there are no header redirects. You're just going to echo whatever info you want passed back whether that is just one value or a whole json encoded array.

Comment: The reason why i have the redirects is that the page should also work if javaScript is not running client side.

Comment: I have a solution to my problem but i want to hear what you think of it.

I can make a function in php like this:

`function is_ajax() {
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "XMLHttpRequest") {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}`

And then set up a IF Else statement like this:

`if (is_ajax() == true) {
 echo 'This is a ajax call';
 //echo the message here
} else {
 echo 'This is not a ajax call';
 //Do the header redirection here
}`

Is there anything wrong doing it this way?

Comment: You're on the right track. The only thing I'm not really sure about is the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header is really reliable.